# Windows 7 equivalent for ntrights.exe

Tags: windows-7, command-line, security

What is an equivalent for `ntrights.exe` on Windows 7?

I need it to be able to be run from the command line.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can still use ntrights from the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17657). Although not supported naturally, many of the tools performs flawlessly (including ntrights.exe).

Proof: [Microsoft TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548356%28WS.10%29.aspx) (scroll down until you find the Tool table, including NTRights.exe as one of the tools that can be used).

Comment: The link to the download now gives a 404.

Comment: The RK is still available at [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20051024013514/http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/e/c/8ec3a7d8-05b4-440a-a71e-ca3ee25fe057/rktools.exe). Download at own risk.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to do it in **Powershell** you can install [Powershell Community Extensions (PSCX)](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx) and use their `Get-Privilege` and `Set-Privilege` cmdlets.

Example from PSCX Help:

```
$p = Get-Privilege
$p.Enable('SeTimeZonePrivilege')
Set-Privilege $p
Get-Privilege | ft Name, Status -a

Name Status
---- ------
SeShutdownPrivilege Disabled
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege EnabledByDefault, Enabled
SeUndockPrivilege Disabled
SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege Disabled
SeTimeZonePrivilege Enabled
```

By default it acts on the current user, but you can pass it a specific windows identity, of course.

Comment: How can I get the identity to pass it, if I want to set a privilege for a different user?

Comment: @PeterMounce Both cmdlets have an _-Identity_ parameter, so you should be a able to specify another user. But I haven't tried that myself.

Comment: I did try that, and it didn't accept a string containing the username as a valid identity; I assume therefore it wants an object.

Comment: @PeterMounce It seems to expect a _System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity_. Couldn't get it to run with another user either.

Comment: yes; how do I get hold of one of those?

Comment: @PeterMounce I could only get a WindowsIdentity for my currently loggend on user. You could post this as a new Powershell question on SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: Note that the `Get-Privilege` cmdlet does **NOT** support all kinds of privileges. For example unsupported are `SeBatchLogonRight` and `SeServiceLogonRight`. See [this](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx/issues/80) issue with a reference to all supported rights.

Answer (score 3):

Although its not suitable for scripting, The [user management plugin](http://plugring.farmanager.com/plugin.php?pid=530&l=en) for the orthodox file manager [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com) will let you do this from the console. If you are running the 64 bit version of farmanager, you will need the 64 bit version of the plugin from the [evil programmers google code project](http://code.google.com/p/evil-programmers/).

Answer (score 0):

Almost ten years laterXD
To show privileges "WhoAmI.exe /Priv" might do it, but "SecEdit.exe" could be worth a look at as well.

Hint: If the command "FSUtil" exits with errorlevel 1, you do *NOT* have admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

`ntrights` may be getting more difficult to find, and certainly isn't supported. For those interested, I wrote an open-source alternative:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PrivMan

You can download the executables from the [Releases](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PrivMan/releases) page.