# Can I create an account on Windows with no Folder or login?

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to figure out a way to create an account on Windows 10 that can provide a login from remote users (I.E. `net use \\Hostname\SharedFilder /User:"Username" Password`) that does **not** have the following:

1. The Ability to Log in from the lock screen
2. It's own folder in C:\Users\

I was messing around with the command `net user /Add` but creating a user this way *did* have the two things I don't want. Disabling the account with `net user Username /Active:No` gets rid of the problems above, but it also blocks it from being logged in.

Comment: Allow only remote authentication for that account in GPEDIT.

Comment: How do I open gpedit?

Comment: I need to be able to do this from the command line unfortunetly

Comment: Win-R. GPEDIT.MSC<Enter>

Comment: Must not be installed on Windows 10 home.

Comment: Look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916590/batch-commands-to-edit-registry-entries-for-local-security-policy-user-rights-as) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/309360/windows-7-equivalent-for-ntrights-exe).

Comment: I’ll try and look into it, it’s a little beyond me. All I’m using are shared folders for a LAN network. Lol

Comment: *All I’m using are shared folders for a LAN network* If so you must forbid local and remote logon but allow network authentication.